# RavenDb Index field attributes

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

For every RavenDb Index field I can specify Storage, Sorting, Indexer and Analyzer. In which cases should I use / not use these attributes?

I tried to find detailed description of these attributes but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is good documentation available here: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/configuring-index-options

As for when to use / not to use them: as your needs demand. Most of the the time, you don't need to create a static index on your own and can just rely on RavenDBs ability to create an indexes dynamically based on your queries. However, if you want to do stuff like full text searching, field storage or map/reduce indexes you will need to define a static index upfront.

Comment: Thank you, it was actually what I needed. I'll just add one more url which describes index Sorting: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/customizing-results-order